# MSSQL: SUM LEFT JOIN GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables:

CSF and CN

```
     CSF                       CN
--------------           ------------------------------------
| CSF-Number |           | Code | CSF | DateTime            |
--------------           -----------------------------------|
| aaa        |           | A    | aaa | 2017-07-03T08:00:00 |
| bbb        |           | B    | ddd | 2017-07-04T08:00:00 |
| ccc        |           | C    | ccc | 2017-07-05T08:00:00 |
| ddd        |           | C    | aaa | 2017-07-06T08:00:00 |
--------------           ------------------------------------
```

As you can see is the CSF-Number the foreign key in table `CN`.

What I try to achieve is to get 2 sums. I want to see how many CSF-Number do have an entry in table CN

The result should look like this:

```
     Result Table
-----------------------
| Description | COUNT |
-----------------------
| With CN     |  75%  |
| Without CN  |  25%  |
-----------------------
```

I am not interested which of the CSF-Numbers have entries. I only want to see the sum as percentage based on the entries in CSF.

I am not new to SQL but somehow I cannot solve this issue :-)

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Note that the table `CN` can have multiple entries for the CSF-Number. (See table CN which has 2 entries for CSF 'aaa')

**UPDATE 2**
Added column DateTime to filter by date and time

Comment: LEFT JOIN seems like a good idea. Then add GROUP BY and you're almost done!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I have no idea how to build the result table structure as these are totally new columns. Any hint?

Comment: Try my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @res decimal(18,2) 

SELECT @res = CAST(100*SUM(CASE WHEN Code IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)/COUNT(*) as decimal(18,2))
FROM CSF s
LEFT JOIN CN n
    ON s.[CSF-Number] = n.CSF

SELECT  'With CN' as [Description],
        @res as [COUNT]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Without CN',
        100-@res
```

Output:

```
Description COUNT
With CN     75.00
Without CN  25.00
```

**Update:**

```
SELECT @res = CAST(100*SUM(CASE WHEN Code IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)/COUNT(*) as decimal(18,2))
FROM CSF s
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM CN 
    WHERE s.[CSF-Number] = CSF
) as n
```

In that case use - OUTER APPLY.

**Some explanation:**

[Here](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/607246/making-outer-and-cross-apply-work-for-you) is a good explanation of OUTER/CROSS APPLY.

Basically, we join 2 tables. Left join (or outer apply, the differnce in that case is that we specify `TOP 1` so we get only first occurrence or no occurrence at all) will bring all the rows from `CSF` table, and all correspondent rows from `CN` table.

If there is no rows in `CN` table - that will bring NULLs. Then we use case statement to make NULLs - 0 and not NULLS - 1, summarize them and here we got number of ocurrences. Multiply by `100`, divide by the count of all CSFs. Here we got percent.

Comment: That's perfect! I have updated the question. What do I have to change if the CSF number is multiple times in table CN?

Comment: You need to count only one occurrence?

Comment: Yes! Even if there are multiple entries for a CSF number the percentage should also be 75%  25%.

Comment: Brilliant! I have no idea what I am doing but it works :-D

Comment: I add some explanation :)

Comment: Where do I have to add the WHERE when I want to filter only rows in table CN where the date is in between a given range (see update 2)

Comment: Works like a charm. Wow!!

Comment: In that case in OUTER APPLY part `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM CN WHERE s.[CSF-Number] = CSF AND [DateTime] = ...`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 'With CN ' AS Description ,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN CN.CSF IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END)/COUNT(CSF.CSFNumber) AS Perc,
FROM CSF 
LEFT JOIN CN ON CSF.CSFNumber = CN.CSF

UNION ALL

SELECT   'Without CN ' AS Description ,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN CN.CSF IS NULL THEN 1 END)/COUNT(CSF.CSFNumber) AS Perc
FROM CSF 
LEFT JOIN CN ON CSF.CSFNumber = CN.CSF
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT
  TotalCount = CAST(COUNT(CSF.CSF_NUMBER) AS NUMERIC(19,2)),
  WithCode = CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN CN.CODE IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NUMERIC(19,2)),
  WithOutCode = CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN CN.CODE IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NUMERIC(19,2))
  FROM CSF
  LEFT JOIN CN
  ON CSF.CSF_NUMBER = CN.CSF
)
SELECT
Description ='With CN',
COUNT  = (WithCode/TotalCount)*100
FROM CTE
UNION ALL
SELECT
Description ='Without CN',
COUNT  = (WithOutCode/TotalCount)*100
FROM CTE
```

Comment: That also works if there is only a single entry for any CSF number in table CN. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT 'With CN' Description,CAST(CAST((SELECT COUNT(CSF) FROM CN)*1.0/(SELECT COUNT(CSF_NUM) FROM CSF)*100 AS NUMERIC(8,0)) AS VARCHAR)+'%' [COUNT]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Without CN' Description,CAST(CAST((SELECT COUNT(CSF_NUM) FROM CSF WHERE CSF_NUM not in(SELECT CSF FROM CN))*1.0/(SELECT COUNT(CSF_NUM) FROM CSF)*100 AS NUMERIC(8,0)) AS VARCHAR)+'%'[COUNT]
```

**OutPut:**

```
Description COUNT
With CN     75%
Without CN  25%
```

**Update1**:

```
SELECT 'With CN' Description,CAST(CAST((SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CSF) FROM CN)*1.0/(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CSF_NUM) FROM CSF)*100 AS NUMERIC(8,0)) AS VARCHAR)+'%' [COUNT]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Without CN' Description,CAST(CAST((SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CSF_NUM) FROM CSF WHERE CSF_NUM not in(SELECT CSF FROM CN))*1.0/(DISTINCT SELECT COUNT(CSF_NUM) FROM CSF)*100 AS NUMERIC(8,0)) AS VARCHAR)+'%'[COUNT]
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! That's almost what I want. What do I have to add if the CSF-Number can have multiple entries in CN table. E.g. CSF 'aaa' is twice in it. The output would be "With CN: 100%, Without 25%" which is obviously wrong

Answer (score 0):

the count function only increments for non-null values, so all one has to count is the codes themselves and any NULLs are automatically accounted for.

```
WITH
      cte AS (
                  SELECT
                        COUNT(CSF.CSF_NUMBER) * 1.0 AS all_csfs
                      , COUNT(CN.CODE)              AS all_cns
                  FROM CSF
                  LEFT JOIN CN ON CSF.CSF_NUMBER = CN.CSF
            )
SELECT
      'With CN'                    AS [description]
    , (all_cns / all_csfs) * 100.0 AS [Count]
FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT
      'Without CN'
    ,  ((all_csfs - all_cns) / all_csfs) * 100.0 
FROM cte
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
SELECT 
    (CASE WHEN N.CSF IS NULL THEN 'Without CN' ELSE 'With CN' END) Description, 
    (100 * COUNT(DISTINCT C.[CSF-Number]) ) / (SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT C.[CSF-Number])) OVER())  [COUNT]
FROM @CSF C 
    LEFT JOIN @CN N ON C.[CSF-Number] = N.CSF
GROUP BY 
    (CASE WHEN N.CSF IS NULL THEN 'Without CN' ELSE 'With CN' END)
```

Result:

```
Description COUNT
----------- -----------
With CN     75
Without CN  25
```

Comment: Works! Thanks you!